# Cannot edit button labels in Glade 3.14.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glade

I cannot edit the buttons label in glade. They are disabled. How can i fix this? Here is the screen shot;

[image]

Comment: ok. Problem was the gnome 3.6

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/201251/9781). In summary, you now need to add a *Related Action* and disable *Use Action Appearance* to be able to edit a button's label in Glade.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [David Planella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049318/david-planella) added above, you can also open the .glade file using a text editor and manually edit the label text. I just tried it and it works.